# How to make image div dispaly on top when window resizes

Tags: html, css

I need to get the image div on top of the page and form div on the bottom of the page when the window resizes. How can i fix this? Any type of help is appreciated

```
.image{

}
```

I need to get the image div on top of the page and form div on the bottom of the page when the window resizes. How can i fix this? Any type of help is appreciated.

Comment: Please, also Edit your question to add HTML code. Also, explain your question.

Comment: You can try based on this example: https://jsfiddle.net/qh90aypz/3/